# How do I echo elements in order of date until 30 elements have been echoed?

Tags: php, ajax, date, loops, while-loop

For an events website, I have a database of events. Each one has an **id**, **title**, and **date** (Y-m-d).

For my page, I want to:

1. Echo all events happening **today**
2. If there aren't at least 30 events today, echo events happening **after today** (in chronological date order) UNTIL at least 30 events are echoed on the page
3. Include a "More" button that echoes the **next 30 events**

I'm currently using AJAX and--on click--replacing "More" with the "more.php" code. What's the best way to infinitely loop this, to where every time you click "More" it loads 30 more events?

Here's my relevant code:

```
<?php
// All events happening today
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE date='$today'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $title = $row['title'];
  $date = $row['date'];
  echo $title;
  echo $date;
  }

// All events for next 9 days
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
  {
  $eventdate = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+$i, date("y")));
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE date='$eventdate'");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $title = $row['title'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    echo $title;
    echo $date;
    }
  }
?>

<!--More button-->
<script type="text/javascript"        
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("more").click(function(){
      $("more").load('more.php');
    });
  });
</script>

<more>More</more>
```

and **more.php**:

```
for ($i=11; $i<=20; $i++)
  {
  $eventdate = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+$i, date("y")));
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE date='$eventdate'");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $title = $row['title'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    echo $title;
    echo $date;
    }
}
// Another "More" button should go here
```

Clearly, I'm not achieving my goals. Right now, it echoes:

1. All events from today (check!)
2. Every single event for the next 9 days (boo)
3. The more page shows every single event for days 11-20 (boo)
4. It doesn't infinitely loop, i.e., I can't click "More" in more.php

I've been trying online tutorials for hours and can't figure out how to achieve this loop I want. Any tips are appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my take on it is this:

1. achieve chronological order by using [SQL Order By](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_order_by.asp) using your date column - i forgot
   how "latest first" is in SQL date (i think it was DESC). either way, just test it.
2. [limit](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm) your query to 30 rows
3. [store in a session](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) the last row (in the beginning, 30).
4. echo the page with the results
5. clicking "More" will load another 30 rows via AJAX but this time, load starting from the (session variable value) + 1. that way, if you loaded the first 30, we now start from 31 - 60. after getting 31 - 60, overwrite the existing session variable so that now it will hold 60.

Comment: +1 Note that there is no `<more>` element in HTML. She probably means `<button id="more">More</button>`.

Comment: pseudo-coding i guess. either way, it's understandable.

Comment: Maybe I missed something, `ORDER BY` the date and the time `WHERE date >= today` and `LIMIT n, 30`. It will automatically include all of today's events up to the limit of 30, or if there are less, some that are `>= today` will be included too. I'm confused by your "If there was only 24 allow them to click more". The query can just fetch everything that's available, and you AJAX back with a new starting value for `n` each time.

Comment: @Leigh i got carried away with the part "loading 30; if not 30, load additional until 30"

Comment: Thanks so much guys! I looked up SQL ORDER BY, Limits and Sessions that @Joseph linked to and got my code going.